# Scrapy - making sure I get all the pages from a domain / how to tell I didn't / what to do about it?

Tags: scrapy, http-status-code-403

I have a pretty generic spider that I do broad crawls with. I feed it a couple hundred starting urls, limit the allowed_domains and let it go wild (I'm following the suggested 'Avoiding getting banned' measures like auto-throttle, no cookies, rotating user agents, rotating proxies etc).

Everything has been going smoothly until like a week ago when the batch of the starting URLs included a pretty big, known domain. At that time, fortunately, I was monitoring the scrape and noticed that the big domain just "got skipped". When looking into why, it seemed that the domain recognized I was using a public proxy and 403ed my initial request to 'https://www.exampledomain.com/', hence the spider didn't find any urls to follow and hence no urls were scraped for that domain.

I then tried using a different set of proxies and/or VPN and that time I was able to scrape some of the pages but got banned shortly after.

The problem with that is that I need to scrape every single page until 3 levels deep. I cannot afford to miss a single one. Also, as you can imagine, missing a request at the default or first level can potentially lead to missing thounsands of urls or no urls being scraped at all.

When a page fails on the initial request it is pretty straight-forward to tell something went wrong. However, when you scrape thousands of urls from multiple domains in one go it's hard to tell if any got missed. And even if I did notice there are 403s and I got banned the only thing to do at that point seems to be to cross my fingers and run the whole domain again since I can't say the urls I missed due to 403s (and all the urls I would get from deeper levels) didn't get scraped from any other urls that contained the 403ed url.

The only thing that comes to mind is to SOMEHOW collect the failed urls, save them to a file at the end of the scrape, make them the starting_urls and run the scrape again. But that would scrape all of the other pages that were successfully scraped previously. Preventing that would require somehow passing a list of successfully scraped urls setting them as denied. But that also isn't a be all end all solution since there are pages you will get 403ed despite not being banned, like resources you need to logged in to see etc.

TLDR: How do I make sure I scrape all the pages from a domain? How do I tell I didn't? What is the best way of doing something about it?

Comment: Have you checked the starts at the end of the output? They indicate failed requests, ignored responses, max retries reached, etc. That should cover the part about knowing if you failed to fetch something.

Comment: Yea, know about that. But imagine scraping a dozen domains, each having tens of thousands of pages. Running the script again from start isn't an option.

Comment: Have you considered using `errback` to yield a custom item for those scenarios indicating the URL and depth, so that you can later read those items from `start_requests` and crawl them?

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing!